# Automatically see my folders in HDFS based on user

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'd like to know how to do this in Hadoop: Say I'm logged in as 'dev'. When I issue this command `hadoop fs -ls /`, I will automatically see the files that belong to me. Like so:

```
# hadoop fs -ls /
/user/dev/mydata1
/user/dev/mydata2
```

The reason for which is we have existing shell scripts that don't have to specify what subfolders in Hadoop to get the data. They only have to call `/mydata1` and it knows it belongs to `/user/dev/`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use

```
hadoop fs -ls .
```

or

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

Comment: But it's got to be the exact command `hadoop fs -ls /` because the scripts all use the '/' prepend. eg. `/mydata1`

Comment: / is the root dir just as a linux file system, run `hadoop fs -ls /` means you want to list everything under the root dir

Comment: Yes, I do know that. In plain Linux file system, this is doable. You can actually configure `ls` command to do `ls ~/Documents`. In our onshore Hadoop configuration, this is how it works. I just don't have access to it and to the person who set it up.

Comment: it seems a strange requirement to me, why do you want to change the default Hadoop behavior instead of to modify a single character in your script...?

Comment: hadoop fs -ls ./mydata1.  What you are asking for is not doable otherwise.